# Interate across Firestore Document in Google Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a google cloud functions that is triggered upon a write to a given document as such

```
exports.copy = functions.firestore.document('original/{userID}/date/{date}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
```

I want to place the data in a new location with

```
return docRef2.doc(`/${xxxxxxx}/copy/date/${yyyyyyyyy}`)
                            .set({ dict });
```

The issue I'm having the data in snap._fieldsProto has a variable number of objects and how I can syntactically iterate over them and place them in a dict

The code I came up with is not working.

```
var dict = {}; // create an empty array

or (i = 0; i < snap._fieldsProto.number_items.integerValue; i++) { 
        var bar = ("item"+String(i))
        dict.bar = snap._fieldsProto.bar.stringValue;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be reaching into the undocumented private properties of the [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.15.x/DocumentSnapshot) object.  Use the documented API methods instead.  You'll want to use the [`data()`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.15.x/DocumentSnapshot#data) method to get a raw javascript object that contains the fields of the document.  You can iterate that just like any other JS object.

Comment: I'll look into it for future functions.  But someone seriously needs to look into making the documentation more user friendly.  There's no to wind up at this pages through organic searching and given I've asked a similar question and a single non-firebase person mentions the data() property I'm assuming I'm not alone.